# Slurm task id as Matlab's function argument

Tags: matlab, slurm

I want to create a job array in slurm in a way such that it is called a Matlab function that depends on the array task id. I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J TEST
#SBATCH -p slims
#SBATCH -o o
#SBATCH -e e

matlab -r "test(${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID})"
```

where test.m is the matlab function that I want to run. This throw the error "Not enough arguments in line 7 test.m ..."

How should I do it?

Comment: Have you tried it without the curly brackets `{}`?

Comment: yes and it didn't work

Comment: @VeridianDynamics, could you post the contents of `test.m`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` was not defined, and there is no `--array` parameter in your submission file. So unless you provided that argument on the command line

```
sbatch --array ... <yourscript.sh>
```

you did not tell Slurm to create an array.

Either add `#SBATCH --array ...` to your submission script or specify it on the command line.